# Searching strings in lists of list for substring

Tags: python, list

I have a list made up of lists of strings:

```
my_list = [[u'Port    Name    Status'],
           [u'Int1    London    connected'],
           [u'Int2    Paris A    disconnected'],
           [u'Port3    Paris A Backup    disabled']]
```

I thought about splitting each string by (" ") and creating tuples as I have worked with them before, but as some of the names are separated this doesn't work.

I want to search each string for items in another list and if it exists pop it from my_list, my full code is

```
my_list = [[u'Port    Name    Status'],
           [u'Int1    London    connected'],
           [u'Int2    Paris A    disconnected'],
           [u'Port3    Paris A Backup    disabled']]

remove_from_list = ['Port', 'connected']

for i in my_list:
    for j in remove_from_list:
        if j in i:
            my_list.pop(i)
```

Aside from not working I also know my code isn't very pythonic, is there a better way with list comprehension to do this?

I want only exact matches to be removed, so an item with *disconnected* stays but *connected* is removed.

Comment: Do you look for exact matches? Should only be `Port` be removed or also `Port3`, only `connected` or also `disconnected`?

Comment: @Cleb sorry, should've said. I want only exact matched removed so only Port but Port3 stays, connected removed but disconnected stays

Comment: looks like your words are separated by groups of 4 spaces. You could split on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This list comprehension should do what you want:

```
[li for li in my_list if not any(wi in li[0].split() for wi in remove_from_list)]
```

This yields

```
[[u'Int2    Paris A    disconnected'],
 [u'Port3    Paris A Backup    disabled']]
```

It uses the idea you mentioned: splitting the entry and then checking whether any of the words is included in the resulting list using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any).

Some more explanation:

```
[li[0].split() for li in my_list]
```

yields

```
[[u'Port', u'Name', u'Status'],
 [u'Int1', u'London', u'connected'],
 [u'Int2', u'Paris', u'A', u'disconnected'],
 [u'Port3', u'Paris', u'A', u'Backup', u'disabled']]
```

That's a new list of lists which we created in a list comprehension; each string is split resulting in a list of single words. Now we have to check whether any of the desired strings are in these sublists which we can do by another list comprehension:

```
[wi in [u'Port', u'Name', u'Status'] for wi in remove_from_list]
[True, False]
```

This list comprehension returns a list with Boolean variables stating whether the elements in `remove_from_list` were found. A quick way to check whether this list contains at least one element equal to `True` is to use `any`:

```
any([True, False])
True
```

and

```
any([False, False])
False
```

Now we can combine these to list comprehensions to expression in the beginning which leaves us with the desired outcome.

One addition, if you want to split based on a regular expression, you can do the following:

```
import re
[re.split('\s{2,}', li[0]) for li in my_list]
```

which gives

```
[[u'Port', u'Name', u'Status'],
 [u'Int1', u'London', u'connected'],
 [u'Int2', u'Paris A', u'disconnected'],
 [u'Port3', u'Paris A Backup', u'disabled']]
```

Difference to above is that you now always end up with only three strings per sublist as you now split only at at least two white spaces. I think that's what you had in mind originally; in your case it does not make a difference as `remove_from_list` contains only single words but if the strings in `remove_from_list` contained whitespaces the first approach would fail: then you should use the one with the regular expression.

The entire command is then

```
[li for li in my_list if not any(wi in re.split('\s{2,}', li[0]) for wi in remove_from_list)]
```

also yielding

```
[[u'Int2    Paris A    disconnected'],
 [u'Port3    Paris A Backup    disabled']]
```

Comment: Really appreciate this, you wouldn't know of any documentation/guides I could take a look at to brush up on this type of thing?

Comment: @CEamonn: I added some more explanation. Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks a lot! Was trying to wrap my head around how li[0].split() wouldn't just give you the first word in each string but makes sense now!

Comment: @CEamonn: Welcome! I added some more stuff so that you can use arbitrary split patters.